# Conventional double integration failed!

Tags: numerical-integration

I was trying to compute the following integration,
$$I = \int_0^{\infty} dt_2\int_0^{\infty} dt_1 \frac{1}{t-t_1-t_2-t_3}\exp{(i\Omega(t_1+t_1+t_1)-i\omega_0t_1)}$$

I have taken $\Omega = 5.12$ and $\omega_0=2.35$. Instead of doing double integration in one NIntegrate, if was trying the following,

```
int1[t_?NumericQ, t2_?NumericQ, t3_?NumericQ]:= 
 NIntegrate[(t - t1 - t2 - t3)^-1*Exp[I*(\[CapitalOmega]*(t1 + t1 + t1) - 
     \[Omega]0*t1)], {t1, 0, \[Infinity]}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]

int2[t_, t3_] := NIntegrate[int1[t, t2, t3], {t2, 0,\[Infinity]}]
```

But the evaluation of int2[1,1] gives the following error,

[image]

I have a difficult time understanding the error. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: For one thing, t3 has no value -- for NIntegrate to work, all variables must be assigned values.

Comment: Should $t_1+t_1+t_1$ be $t_1+t_2+t_3$ in both the integration and *Mathematica* code?

Comment: I have edited the question. Actually, int2 have two parameters, so I want to evaluate at any value of t and t3. I tried for t=1 and t3=1

Comment: @JimB No, I get it why you think that but that is just 3*t1, I just copy paste from my notebook.

Comment: Is it because the power ```-1``` is not in parenthesis?

Answer (score 1):

Do first integration anylytically with Integrate to see, second integral does not converge.

```
f = (t - t1 - t2 - t3)^-1*
    Exp[I*(\[CapitalOmega]*(t1 + t1 + t1) - \[Omega]0*
         t1)] /. {\[CapitalOmega] -> 512/100, \[Omega]0 -> 235/100};

int1[t_, t2_, t3_] = 
 Integrate[f, {t1, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> Thread[{t, t2, t3} > 0]]

(*   ConditionalExpression[-I E^(
  1301/100 I (t - t2 - t3)) (\[Pi] + 
    I ExpIntegralEi[-(1301/100) I (t - t2 - t3)]), t < t2 + t3]   *)
```

NIntegrate Integrate faile both. Series shows, int1 to go to infinity according to 1/t2, means it does not converge. Behavior at zero is integrable.

```
NIntegrate[int1[1, t2, 1] // Normal, {t2, 0, Infinity}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 500, AccuracyGoal -> 5]

ser0 = Series[int1[1, t2, 1], {t2, 0, 0}, Assumptions -> t2 > 0] // 
  Normal

(*   EulerGamma - (I \[Pi])/2 + Log[1301/100] + Log[t2]   *) 

ser1 = Series[int1[1, t2, 1], {t2, Infinity, 1}] // Normal

(*   -((100 I)/(1301 t2))   *)
```